# Kendo Telerik reporting is very slow when loading large data (bad performance) and a message of 0 pages loaded so far is appeared

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, reporting

I am using kendo report, my client has huge data (millions), my sp return data in 46 s, put generating the report is taken more than 30 min and more.  **A message of 0 pages loaded so far is annoying**.
I am searching to find a way to **progressive** downloads the report without waiting too much time to generate all pages.
I have read carefully  the [Performance Considerations](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-performance?&_ga=2.178691748.1412503996.1619342074-249661142.1600328222#performance-factors-in-the-developer-s-control)
I removed the pageCount in the bottom of every page, I did not see big difference.
My client also has very high specification for hardware.
The report contains two images per row, which I can not remove them. as you can see in the image

[this screen shot of how the report is appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsuoD.png)
I need to fast loading the report in any way! please help me

Comment: Does the report need to pull and display the all the rows of data that your sp returns at all times? Is there any way to re-work it a bit like maybe showing all the possible months (or quarters, or hours - depends on your data) that have data, then clicking a month (or quarter) drills down and pulls the data associated  with that date range? I know this isn't what you're asking for, but just an idea.

Comment: are you using the latest version of report viewer and ASP.NET server? I have reports that load pages slowly up to 4,000 and show progress